# ef core migrate data when migration applies

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

So how do you migrate data when a migration gets applied?

Scenario:

Now I have a table

```
Item:
Id | Name | Image | ImageWidth | ImageHeight | ...

Label:
Id | ItemId | ...
```

Se every item in the database has one image.
I now need to go to a list of images per item instead of a single image.

```
Item:
Id | Name | ICollection<Image> | ...

Image:
Id | ItemId | Image | ImageWidth | ImageHeight

Label:
Id | ImageId | ...
```

How do I write migrations that take all data from the `Item` and insert that into the new `Image` table, with the foreign key preserved. If that succeeded then remove the old columns from the `Item` table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to order operations in migration file like this:

1. Create `Image` table;
2. Create images using data from `Item` table;
3. Drop columns from `Item` table.

In second step it will be like:

```
INSERT INTO Image (ItemId, Image, ImageWidth, ImageHeight, ...) VALUES (Item.Id, Item.Iamge, Item.ImageWidth, Item.ImageHeight, ...);
```

But I'm not sure about it.

Comment: It's easy to go from 1 table to 2. But I've also got the Label table that references `Item` but now needs to reference `Image`

Comment: Yeah, I see. You can get `image id` by `item id` from `Label` table because we know that only one `image` has exact `item id`. I'm bad with sql queries, but I think it will be look like 
`SELECT Image.Id FROM Image JOIN Label ON Image.ItemId = Label.ItemId`.